# Equation alignment in aligned environment not working properly

Tags: equations, horizontal-alignment, aligned

So I want the beginning and the middle part of equations to align. But the output is misaligned at both locations. Appreciate any tips. I don't want to use alignat as it does not place a single equation number in the center.

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
     & \minimize_{X} & PX \\
     & \text{subject to} & X \le 0 \\
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
```

[image]

Comment: you put PX in a right-aligned column so it is aligned with 0 on the line below

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One of the following two?

- In the first equation, material is right-aligned before the `&` symbol and left-aligned thereafter.
- In the second equation, material is left-aligned in both columns.

  Note that I wrote `{\minimize_{X}}` instead of just `\minimize_{X}`, to override the setting that would insert thinspace before `\minimize` (since it's of type `mathop`).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'alignedat' environment
\DeclareMathOperator*{\minimize}{minimize} % ??
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
     \min_{X}\          & PX \\
     \text{subject to } & X \le 0 \\
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

\bigskip
\begin{equation}
\begin{alignedat}{2}
     &{\minimize_{X}}   &  & PX \\
     &\text{subject to} &\ & X \le 0 \\
\end{alignedat}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: How do I align beginning of min and subject as well?

Comment: @dsp_guy2020 - Please see the second solution I just posted.

Comment: Thank you so much. Exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

Using `optidef` package a Latex library for optimization problems.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{optidef}
\begin{document}
\begin{mini}
{\scriptstyle X}{ PX }{}{}
\addConstraint {X }{\leq 0}{}
\end{mini}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Or with a short code \begin{mini}`|s|`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{optidef}
\begin{document}
\begin{mini}|s|
{\scriptstyle X}{ PX }{}{}
\addConstraint { X }{\leq 0}{}
\end{mini}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: But the *X* applied to `\min` is too large.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Done!! I have changed with `\scriptstyle X`.

Comment: @Mico Dearest Mico I have done the changed with `\scriptstyle X`. Thank you very much.